# How to find out which library includes which support library version

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I get following warning:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification...
```

I know what that means, but now I'm stuck on how to easily find out which dependency does include the conflicting versions. I want to exclude the support library from them like following:

```
compile ('...')  {
    exclude group: 'android.support'
}
```

But **how** do I identify the dependencies that are responsible?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817875/3012993) with screenshot and explaination of Gradle dependency tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can watch **full gradle dependency tree** tree using the command below-

```
gradle app:dependencies
```

[Reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies)