# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

I am building an application with firebase but getting the Duplicate class error. I have checked all dependencies, but I'm not able to figure out where did I have two version of firebase libs. Error:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/iid/zzb$1.class

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.palmtickle"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //Enabling multiDex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //support and app compatibility libs
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.1.1'

    //entries related to firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-base:r03'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0-native'
}
```

As I always try to solve errors like this by searching duplicate files in Android Studio. When I search class **zzb** in android studio, I am getting a jar **firebase-iid-9.0.0**  with all other 10.2.1 firebase classes. I am not able to find out which dependency is injecting this firebase-iid-9.0.0 jar? Any idea?

Comment: Check out my answer to get full `gradle` dependency - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945613/how-to-find-out-which-library-includes-which-support-library-version/42945708#42945708

Answer (score 9):

Try to update `buildToolsVersion to 25.0.2`

I face same issue today, and I try to use

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
```

clean project and rebuild project
everything is all right

check support library is version 25.3.0 on each module, and make sure all the firebase module is 10.2.1

Comment: It seems I was missing firebase core lib: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1' . I didn't know this analytics lib is neccessory?I am still in doubt that if this core lib is must have or not.

Comment: @MahendraChhimwal Check the setup page. It is not mandatory, but it is high recommended. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @MahendraChhimwal Yes some analytics feature need Core, like remove times, install times, first_open, session_start, in your Firebase dashboard→Analytics→events

Comment: I love you. It work for my Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/iid/zzb$1.class

Answer (score 7):

For me it was dependency issue with version number using with google play services library and firebase library. Use following command to see dependency tree:

```
gradlew :app:dependencies
```

Output:

[image]

check your library version. here version in left side of -> is requested version and version at right side of -> is picked version by gradle.

So I updated my google play services library version and firebase library version to 11.0.1 in app level build.gradle file.

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1"   
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
```

you can see google play services library versions [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90)